# Android NavigationView menu icon problems

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to change the icons of the menu items in my navigation view when they are clicked. To do this i am using the following method:

```
private void selectDrawerItem(final MenuItem menuItem){

    for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getMenu().size(); i++){
        Log.e(TAG, "Clearing " + navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getItemId() + " " + navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getIcon());
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(i).getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
    }

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        default:
            break;

        case R.id.drawer_item_one:
            menuItem.getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.accent));
            Log.e(TAG, "Setting " + menuItem.getItemId() + " " + menuItem.getIcon());
            break;
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "-----END-----");

    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    //drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

The problem is that whenever i click the first item, it correctly resets all the icons to white, but then it sets the selected icon to the accent color AND the previous 2 menu items that i clicked. I don't understand what is happening. The logs clearly show that it is only setting the background color one time, so why are 3 of them getting set?

It seems like any drawer item that i add to the switch statement causes the previous 3 items to also change background colors. What is happening?

**EDIT**

If i replace the code in the switch statement, and just add a delay, it seems to work:

```
case R.id.drawer_item_one:
            new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    menuItem.getIcon().setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_dark));
                }
            }, 50);
            break;
```

I don't want to add a delay though, how can i make this work without the strange workaround?

**EDIT 2**

Another thing i have noticed is that if instead of changing the color, i change the title text, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_selected_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_selected_item"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

----------------------------------------------------------------
 navigation_selected_item.xml

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This is used when the Navigation Item is checked -->
    <item android:color="@color/selected_color" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!-- This is the default text color -->
    <item android:color="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I'm trying to have a different selected color for each item so this wont work